# Convert XML to XML for Each Item

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

Good Afternoon, 
I am very new to XML and XSLT and I am trying to Convert the first XML below, to the second XML below.  Any help would be appreciated.  The XML is for a data feed, so it would need to stay in the same format as the original, but what I need it to do is to create a separate "item" for each "Document_to_be_Requested," per "Questionnaire_ID."

ORIGINAL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ex:Record xmlns:ex="http://archertech.com/Print/Export">

    <ex:Item>
        <ex:Questionnaire_ID>1007</ex:Questionnaire_ID>
        <ex:Target>
            <ex:Item>Company 1</ex:Item>
        </ex:Target>
        <ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
            <ex:Item>A</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>C</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>D</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>F</ex:Item>
        </ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
    </ex:Item>

    <ex:Item>
        <ex:Questionnaire_ID>1009</ex:Questionnaire_ID>
        <ex:Target>
            <ex:Item>Company 2</ex:Item>
        </ex:Target>
        <ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
            <ex:Item>A</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>B</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>F</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>G</ex:Item>
        </ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
    </ex:Item>
</ex:Record>
```

DESIRED

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ex:Record xmlns:ex="http://archertech.com/Print/Export">

<ex:Item>
    <ex:Questionnaire_ID>1007</ex:Questionnaire_ID>
    <ex:Target>
        <ex:Item>Company 1</ex:Item>
    </ex:Target>
    <ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
        <ex:Item>A</ex:Item>
    </ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
</ex:Item>

<ex:Item>
    <ex:Questionnaire_ID>1007</ex:Questionnaire_ID>
    <ex:Target>
        <ex:Item>Company 1</ex:Item>
    </ex:Target>
    <ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
        <ex:Item>C</ex:Item>
    </ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
</ex:Item>

<ex:Item>
    <ex:Questionnaire_ID>1007</ex:Questionnaire_ID>
    <ex:Target>
        <ex:Item>Company 1</ex:Item>
    </ex:Target>
    <ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
        <ex:Item>D</ex:Item>
    </ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
</ex:Item>

<ex:Item>
    <ex:Questionnaire_ID>1007</ex:Questionnaire_ID>
    <ex:Target>
        <ex:Item>Company 1</ex:Item>
    </ex:Target>
    <ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
        <ex:Item>F</ex:Item>
    </ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
</ex:Item>


<ex:Item>
    <ex:Questionnaire_ID>1009</ex:Questionnaire_ID>
    <ex:Target>
        <ex:Item>Company 2</ex:Item>
    </ex:Target>
    <ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
        <ex:Item>A</ex:Item>
    </ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
</ex:Item>

<ex:Item>
    <ex:Questionnaire_ID>1009</ex:Questionnaire_ID>
    <ex:Target>
        <ex:Item>Company 2</ex:Item>
    </ex:Target>
    <ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
        <ex:Item>B</ex:Item>
    </ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
</ex:Item>

<ex:Item>
    <ex:Questionnaire_ID>1009</ex:Questionnaire_ID>
    <ex:Target>
        <ex:Item>Company 2</ex:Item>
    </ex:Target>
    <ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
        <ex:Item>F</ex:Item>
    </ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
</ex:Item>

<ex:Item>
    <ex:Questionnaire_ID>1009</ex:Questionnaire_ID>
    <ex:Target>
        <ex:Item>Company 2</ex:Item>
    </ex:Target>
    <ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
        <ex:Item>G</ex:Item>
    </ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
</ex:Item>


</ex:Record>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a coding service. If you have a specific question or difficulty, show us what you did and point it out. -- Note that the input you show is not well-formed XML and cannot be processed by XSLT at all (no single root element, and a prefix not bound to a namespace).

Comment: The root got cut off, it was the same as the second one 
<ex:Record>
</ex:Record>

Comment: Can you at least give me a hint on where to start.  I have been trying for 2 days and I am clearly misunderstanding something about XSLT that is preventing if from working at all.

Comment: It seems pretty basic to me: create an item for each `ex:Item/ex:Document_to_be_Requested/ex:Item` and copy some nodes from the ancestor `ex:Item` node.

Comment: <xsl:template match="ex:Record">
  <xsl:for-each select= "ex:Record/ex:Item/ex:Document_to_be_Requested/ex:Item" >
   <xsl:value-of select="ex:Record/ex:Item/ex:Document_to_be_Requested/ex:Item" />
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

Answer (score 0):

Start with an identity template

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then have a template match for `ex:Record/ex:Item` node. Applying only the target nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="ex:Record/ex:Item">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ex:Document_to_be_Requested/*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Then a template for the target node

```
<xsl:template match="ex:Document_to_be_Requested/ex:Item">
    <ex:Item>
        <!-- copies the preceding siblings of parent node -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="../preceding-sibling::*"/>
        <ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
            <!-- copies the current node -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
    </ex:Item>
</xsl:template>
```

The whole stylesheet is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ex="http://archertech.com/Print/Export"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ex:Record/ex:Item">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ex:Document_to_be_Requested/*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ex:Document_to_be_Requested/ex:Item">
        <ex:Item>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../preceding-sibling::*"/>
            <ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </ex:Document_to_be_Requested>
        </ex:Item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Dp).